# Issue with callback functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three dropdowns I am trying to dynamically populate when an HTML form loads. They all use API callback functions provided by a third-party cloud database provider to retrieve the data and populate the dropdowns. The problem I am encountering is that only the last one populates. Here is how I'm calling the functions:

```
$(function ()
{
    PopulateDropdown('OwnerList');
});

$(function()
{
    PopulateDropdown('ClientList');
});

$(function ()
{
    PopulateDropdown('AssignedToList');
});
```

The text inside the parentheses are the IDs of the dropdowns (select elements) in the HTML.

The only dropdown that ever gets populated is whichever the last one in the list is. The code as shown above populates only the AssignedToList dropdown. If I move the call to populate the AssignedToList to the top, moving the ClientList to the bottom, only the ClientList dropdown populates. I am fairly new to JavaScript and jQuery, so I'm sure there's a way to ensure all three calls work properly. I have Googled everything I can think of but haven't been able to find anything to help. I'm not even real sure what it is I need to Google! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The secret lies inside the `PopulateDropdown()` function. Post it too...

Comment: Can you expand the code you've shown? I'm wondering if the block of code shown is something you're including as a callback parm in a function or something.

Comment: Hi...I want to post the code but don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This'd how you combine the 3 into a single function:

```
$(function () {
    PopulateDropdown('OwnerList');
    PopulateDropdown('ClientList');
    PopulateDropdown('AssignedToList');
});
```

Comment: Is this what the OP was asking for?

Comment: Seems more likely to me that `PopulateDropdown` clears all three dropdowns then populates whichever one you pass in.

Comment: Well, this actually may be the right answer if the OP is using the OP code as a callback parm.

Comment: @mike: you're probably right. but unless the OP shows that chunk of code, no way to be sure.

Comment: You can call the `$()` function as many times as you want, it will just add onload handlers: http://jsfiddle.net/6dumD/